# Vs2008 on server 2008, setup for debugging wtih https: (cert install?)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to install a cert to allow me to debug my code that takes a http request and response redirects to the same url on https.

I suspect my certs need to be setup for this to work.

I tried to follow the instructions here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx

but I'm on server 2008, not XP so I think I need to use "netsh http add sslcert <...>"

Does anyone have a good tutorial on getting a website set up to debug with https in vs2008 on server 2008, or even something closer than the one above, or alternately can you tell em what I need to do from here?

I did the following steps but got stuck

1. make trusted root cert:

   makecert -sv SignRoot.pvk -cy authority -r signroot.cer -a sha1 -n "CN=Dev Certification Authority" -ss my -sr localmachine

Drag and drop to trusted root / certs

2.make real cert with above:

```
makecert -iv SignRoot.pvk -ic signroot.cer -cy end -pe -n CN="localhost" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localmachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

1. Assign cert (this step fails)

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=‎5618434be3b2bb1b90caca3b929a28c2f1b854fa appid={5dcdf96e-29d8-4055-903e-7dc5f90f77db}

I think it's complaining about the cert hash, which is just the cert thumbprint without the spaces right?
(the guid is my app guid from the CSproj)

Thanks,

Eric-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, sorry I didn't get back to answer this earlier.

As I remember, IIS wan't getting under Network Service on server 2008, and my permissiosn were set up on NetworkService. once we changed teh defautl user for ISS it worked.

Thanks,

Eric-